# Running multiple threads concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading

Good day all, for running multiple threads concurrently is it advisable to create different thread objects from a class or create two classes where one implements runnable and one extends a thread and then create thread objects from both of them as needed assuming we are trying to run 7- 10 tasks concurrently.

1. whats are the best solutions?..
2. Are there any pitfalls or performance hit, if one creates different thread objects from a single class?.

Thank you. Tips appreciated as always.

Comment: A thread and a process are two different things. If you mean thread, then use the term "thread", not the term "process".

Comment: Do you really mean operating system processes? That's what processes usually means in the context of programming; if you actually mean jobs or tasks, avoid using the word process because it will confuse other programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally go for **option(1)** (Creating 2 different threads of the same class).

I don't feel there's need to create 2 different classes for the job that can be done by 2 different threads of the same class.

Answer (score 19):

1. Take a look at the great `java.util.concurrent` package
2. There are no performance pitfalls out of creating different thread objects from a single class

Here's a short example:

```
private static class SomeTask implements Runnable
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    doSomething();
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) executor.execute(new SomeTask());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it matters which way you do it. If you're going to be having a lot of short lived threads you'll probably want a thread pool, see java.util.concurrent.Executors. Usually I create an  annonymous class of type runnable, e.g.

```
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    //thread code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There's little difference in performance between creating a thread by extending Thread or by implementing Runnable and using `new Thread(runnable)`. Whether using one class or several is also irrelevant. You should design your class structure based on the work to be done; if two threads are doing the same work on different data, use the same class for both.

Access to shared data (whether static class variables or something else) is always a big issue.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing that makes the difference is how you have designed your object hierarchy:
If you extend Thread class, you can't extend any other classes (Java is single Inheritance). so by  Implementing the Runnable, you can still extend other classes in your domain model.